# How to scroll to button's position in scrollView

Tags: swift, scroll, scrollview

I have scrollView and button at about at middle at scrollView. I want to scroll to this button, using button y-position, how can i do it?

I can scroll to the top or bottom of the scrollView, but I can't don't know how to scroll to the exact position of some element

[Image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocYi5.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use `UIScrollView`
`open func scrollRectToVisible(_ rect: CGRect, animated: Bool)` method.
This method allows you to scroll to a particular frame.

```
scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(/*Button frame*/, animated: true)
```

---

Note:
Suppose your button is in multiple subviews then you first need to find the button frame from the scrollView and then scroll.

```
let buttonFrame = yourButton.superview?.convert(yourButton.frame, from: scrollView)
scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(buttonFrame ?? .zero, animated: true)
```

Comment: Scroll don't work. Buttons postion - Optional((-15.0, -211.99999999999994, 398.0, 18.666666666666657))

Comment: How you code? I think you are passing the wrong frame.

Comment: let buttonFrame = self.deliveryTransportAddressLabel.superview?.convert(self.deliveryTransportAddressLabel.frame, from: self.scrollView)
                
self.scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(buttonFrame ?? .zero, animated: true)

Comment: In which life cycle method this code written?

Comment: When i press button "Make order"

Comment: I'm attached screenshot (red button - it's make order button)

Comment: I test this code and works for me. You just get the wrong button frame just find the correct frame and use this scroll method. If your button is directly inside the scroll view then you can just pass frame without convert.

Comment: Yes, send button also on scrollView

Comment: self.scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(self.deliveryTransportAddressLabel.frame, animated: true) - still don't work

Comment: As per the question I given answer but you have to find first correct position of the button.

Comment: I had the same issue but after changing "from" to "to", it works like a charm:
let buttonFrame = yourButton.superview?.convert(yourButton.frame, to: scrollView)